# How to escape double dollars in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, grep, escaping, dollar-sign

Consider a directory containing (only) the 3 files obtained by:

```
echo "foobar" > test1.txt
echo "\$foobar" > test2.txt
echo "\$\$foobar" > test3.txt
```

(and thus containing respectively `foobar`, `$foobar`, `$$foobar`).

The `grep` instruction:

```
grep -l -r --include "*.txt" "\\$\\$" .
```

filters the files (actually, the unique file) containing double dollars:

```
$ grep -l -r --include "*.txt" "\\$\\$" .
./test3.txt
```

So far, so good. Now, this instruction fails within a makefile, e.g.:

```
doubledollars:
    echo "Here are files containing double dollars:";\
    grep -l -r --include "*.txt" "\\$\\$" . ;\
    printf "\n";\
```

leads to the errors:

```
$ make doubledollars
echo "Here are files containing double dollars:";\
grep -l -r --include "*.txt" "\\\ . ;\
printf "\n";\

/bin/sh: -c: ligne 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: ligne 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
makefile:2: recipe for target 'doubledollars' failed
make: *** [doubledollars] Error 1
```

Hence my question: how to escape *double* dollars in a makefile?

**Edit:** note that this question does not involve Perl.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320226/four-dollar-signs-in-makefile

Comment: You escape `$` in a makefile recipe by doubling it `$$`. See [Using Variables in Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-in-Recipes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quote a perl $symbol in a makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691180/how-to-quote-a-perl-symbol-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

with following `Makefile`

```
a:
  echo '$$$$'
```

`make a` gives

```
$$
```

... and it's better to use single quotes if you do not need variable expansion:

```
grep -l -r -F --include *.txt '$$' .
```

unless you write script to be able to be executed on Windows in MinGW environment, of cause.

Comment: But `grep -l -r --include '*.txt' '$$$$' .` (with single quotes and doubling each of the dollars) does *not* the job within a makefile for filtering the files containing double dollars.

Comment: The dollar sign is a metacharacter in `grep` so it needs to be backslash-escaped or included in a character class.  Try `grep .... '\$$\$$' .` or `grep .... '[$$][$$]' .` where the doubled dollar signs are still required in order to escape it from Make.

Comment: I'm sorry, of cause you have to omit single quotes so wildcard would work. Corrected an answer.

Comment: @tripleee, or use grep -F